# Ruby HTTPClient set header for get method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I set a header in Ruby HTTP Client? I want my header to be like

```
client = HTTPClient.new
url = "https://dummyurl.com"
headers = { "id": "x", "pass": "y" }
response = client.get(url)
```

how should i put the headers? thank you

Answer (score 1):

`.get` has a signature of

`get(uri, query = nil, extheader = {}, &block)`

You pass either an object or an array of objects as `extheader` to set any additional headers, e.g.

`response = client.get(url, nil, headers)`

per your example.